# convert unicode into character with ruby

Tags: ruby, unicode, cjk

I found a dictionary of Chinese characters in unicode. I'm trying to build a database of Characters out of this dictionary but I don't know how to convert unicode to a character..

```
p "国".unpack("U*").first #this gives the unicode 22269
```

How can convert `22269` back into the character value which would be the opposite of the line above.

Comment: What version of Ruby are you using?

Comment: I have rvm so it doesn't matter. Anything suggestions including 1.9.2 are welcome.

Comment: If you are converting a lot of text you might want to look at Ruby's [IConv](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/iconv/rdoc/index.html) module, which is part of the core library. [rubydoc.info](http://rubydoc.info/stdlib/iconv/1.9.2/frames) also has the docs. And James Edward Gray did a nice article called [Encoding Conversion With iconv](http://blog.grayproductions.net/articles/encoding_conversion_with_iconv). The nice thing about IConv is it can transliterate, ie, change to similar looking characters, or ignore, when there is no match, so your conversion degrades in a controlled way.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
[22269].pack('U*') #=> "国" or "\345\233\275"
```

**Edit**: Works in 1.8.6+ (verified in 1.8.6, 1.8.7, and 1.9.2). In 1.8.x you get a three-byte string representing the single Unicode character, but using `puts` on that causes the correct Chinese character to appear in the terminal.

Comment: @Sam Apparently it didn't matter what version you were using. (See edit) :)

Comment: "Apparently it didn't matter what version you were using." lol.

Comment: One can use `C` for ASCII + `unpack` for the reverse operation. Just FYI readers.

Answer (score 16):

Ruby 1.9 :

```
p "国".codepoints.first #=> 22269
p 22269.chr('UTF-8') #=> "国"
```

Comment: @Sam Which version of ruby did you use?

Comment: @Sam codepoints is a method of String in 1.9.2 : http://ruby-doc.org/ruby-1.9/classes/String.html#M000607 . Don't know what's going wrong. Works here.