# ruby: unicode character decimal value to \uXXXX conversion? .ord method not working

Tags: ruby, unicode, decimal

I'm trying to work with unicode characters, and the information provided by the string's .ord method doesn't help me.  I'm used to working with codes like "\uXXXX".

```
ruby-1.9.3-p0 :119 > form[0]
=> "כ" 

ruby-1.9.3-p0 :120 > form[0].ord
=> 1499 
ruby-1.9.3-p0 :121 > puts "\u1499"
ᒙ
```

...

:-(

The values yielded by .ord seem to correspond to the 'decimal points' referred to here:
http://www.i18nguy.com/unicode/hebrew.html

I don't know how to work with these values.  How do I get the \uXXXX code from that character?

Thank you

Comment: I found out how to pack that decimal value back into a unicode character @ http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4620549/convert-unicode-into-character-with-ruby , but would still like to know how to get the other code.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

mu is too short's answer is cool.

But, the simplest answer is:

```
'好'.ord.to_s(16)     # => '597d'
```

Comment: You are right~. Thanks. althougth you can use `5db` like this: `puts "\u{5db}"`

Answer (score 16):

The `\u` syntax uses hexadecimal, you're giving it a decimal value. You want:

```
>> "%4.4x" % form[o].ord
"05db"
>> puts "\u05db"
כ
```

Comment: Thanks!  What's the "%4.4x" % part doing?

Comment: @WalrustheCat: http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/String.html#method-i-25, `"%.4x"` is sufficient though.

Comment: I prefer the more self-explanatory form `%04x` for zero padding.

Comment: How can I use "\u" syntax in script? So basically what I want is:

`code = "0028"
character = "\u#{0028}" # => "(" Expected
character = "\\u#{0028}" # => "(" Expected`

Both of the above does not work. Any suggestions?

Comment: @Agent47DarkSoul: [`Array#pack`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Array.html#method-i-pack) is one way: `['05db'.to_i(16)].pack('U')` is `'כ'` for example.

Comment: @muistooshort figured it out: `['0028'.hex].pack('U*')` returns `'('`. Thanks!